# SP2007 - How to display textbox field element based on dropdown menu choice on Edit Column page?

Tags: column, custom-field-types, caml

I'm creating a custom list field type which is basically a glorified multichoice field, but I want the checkboxes to be grouped by headings that the user can specify.  For example:

```
Status1
    SubStatus1
    SubStatus2
Status2
    SubStatus3
    SubStatus4
    SubStatus5
```

where the statuses are headings and the substatuses are checkboxes.  I want the user to be able to specify these when they create the column in the list or if they go to the Edit Column page:

[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/442/substatus.png/)

When the user selects one of the Statuses from the dropdown, I want the SubStatus textbox to populate the choices that should be placed under that heading (which the user should be able to edit).  I've been playing around with using CAML in my fldtypes*.xml file in the PropertySchema with no success.  Can this be done and is using CAML the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea from the below link :

http://kishansharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/showhide-lookup-fields-with-jquery.html

Thanks